Scroll bar on interactive grid
I have one interactive grid in which i have 8 column out of which left 5 column is non editable and right 3 column is editable. So I want to apply scroll bar only on the 3 column which is editable. How can I achieve this functionality.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You can assign different class to non-editable  and editable columns.


 body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
            gap: 10px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .non-editable {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            padding: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .editable {
            background-color: #d0d0d0;
            padding: 10px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
        .editable[contenteditable="true"] {
            outline: none;
        }
  <div class="container">
        <div class="non-editable">Column 1 (Non-Editable)</div>
        <div class="non-editable">Column 2 (Non-Editable)</div>
        <div class="non-editable">Column 3 (Non-Editable)</div>
        <div class="non-editable">Column 4 (Non-Editable)</div>
        <div class="non-editable">Column 5 (Non-Editable)</div>
        <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Column 6 (Editable)<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content</div>
        <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Column 7 (Editable)<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content</div>
        <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Column 8 (Editable)<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content</div>
    </div>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
